# How to add/append JavaScript sourced data into an existing DataTables Table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am working on [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/vaf3L2hn/1/). How can I add JavaScript sourced data into an existing table?

I have seen this [example](https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html) on Datatables website but this looks like only one time process and in my case I need to truncate and load the  `dataset[]` after each query add eventually add the result in the table as a new row.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var dataSet = ["Tiger", "Wood ", "Architect", "F15", "36", "Feb, 15"];
  $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
    'copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'csv']
  });
  $("#addData").on("click", function(){
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DataTables API to add rows.
You need to pass an array of values (columns):

```
var dt;

$(document).ready(function () {
    var dataSet = ["Tiger", "Wood ", "Architect", "F15", "36", "Feb, 15"];
    dt = $('#example').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'csv']
    });

    $("#addData").on("click", function(){
        dt.row.add(["Whatever else"]).draw(false); 
    });
});
```

You can refer to this [DataTables official example](https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html).